# Splunk - How can I get accumulative vales for a day for a period of time?

Tags: splunk, accumulate

One of the things I'm using Splunk to monitor is electricity usage, one of the fields indexed is the accumulative Kw value for the day, how can I get the last value for the day for a given timespan? So output the total Kw for each day for a month - I've tried using

```
host=Electricity earliest=-4w@w1 latest=+w@w1 | timechart last(live_day_kw) as Kw
```

but for the data I have it seems to be adding each day together so its increasing day on day and not daily values, so for example day1 is 7kw and day2 is 14kw and day3 is 21kw - I'd expect it to be ~7kw a day. Also just checked and the `live_day_kw` value does reset to zero at midnight

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure of what you're looking for, but maybe this will help.

```
host=Electricity earliest=-4w@w1 latest=+w@w1 | timechart span=1d last(live_day_kw) as Kw
```

Comment: Hi Thanks - It works but doesn't return the values I'm after, in pseudo code I'm after - search last month to today and for each day get the last value for 'live_day_kw'

Comment: Here are a couple other searches to try.

`host=Electricity earliest=-4w@w1 latest=+w@w1 | timechart span=1d max(live_day_kw) as Kw`
Or
`host=Electricity earliest=-4w@w1 latest=+w@w1 | stats max(live_day_kw) as Kw by date_mday`

Comment: For the benefit of those searching for the same solution I managed to solve it thus: `host=Electricity earliest=-4w@w1 | timechart latest(live_day_kw) as "Kw_Day" | eval Kw_Day = round(Kw_Day,2)` and set the search to the last month

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of those looking for the same solution I managed to solve it thus:

```
host=Electricity earliest=-4w@w1 | timechart latest(live_day_kw) as "Kw_Day" | eval Kw_Day = round(Kw_Day,2)
```

Also needed the search set to 'month to date' and it get exactly what I needed.